# How to take a space as input in scanf() ie in c?

Tags: c

I want to store a few numbers in an array. While giving the input though, I cannot use an enter to move from one position to the next. I need to use a space.

Eg:

```
input:2 3 4 5
```

instead of:

```
input: 2
3
4
5
```

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can just go ahead with scanning an integer like

```
int a[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  if(scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1)
  break;
}
```

`%d` will consider an integer input until an newline or a space is encountered.

Comment: The great question remaining is: what is your loop doing when the user enters ` 2 y . 5`?

Comment: What do you mean its not halting?

Comment: I don't think @April knows you still have to terminate the entry with `Enter`.

Comment: Didn't you edit the answer in reponse to @ott's comment by adding the check to the return value from `scanf`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't go by ott's comment.. I felt the check is good here and added .. ok now it get that even ott meant the same

Comment: @AprilEmerson After inputting 5 integers separated by space press enter

Comment: Yes, I just now got to know about it. Thank you very much @WeatherVane

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf ("Enter 4 integers: ");
    if (4 != scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d))
        printf ("Invalid input\n");
    else
        printf ("You entered %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Enter 4 integers: 2 3 4 5
You entered 2 3 4 5
```

Be aware though that if you only enter 3 integers you won't get the error message, because the program is still waiting for a fourth. You get the error if the inputs were not integers.

And note that you have to terminate the input with `Enter` key.

Comment: Will you please explain that if condition?

Comment: The function `scanf` returns the number of fields successfully converted, as the manual says!

Comment: I just read that last part..terminate with 'enter' key! I thought the process of taking input stops once you're out of the for loop.

Comment: It is called "buffered" input. As an aside, I can't understand why there is no function in standard C to input a single character from a keyboard.

Comment: I didn't get the last part. A single character meaning? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: You could solve your problem by building the integers from the numerals typed, as they are typed, stopping after the fourth one, if only there was a C function to input a single character. But all the standard input functions require a terminating `Enter` unless either (a) you fiddled with the OS to cancel keboard input buffering - obviously OS specific, or (b) you use a nonstandard library function such a `getch()` in MSVC, which returns immediately a charater is typed.